# Having an issue with deleting cookies under ASP.NET MVC3 w/ jquery.cookies & IIS6 pathing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-blockui

Recently I was looking into how I could provide a progress indicator, or busy indicator to a user when downloading a whole bunch of data in an Excel spreadsheet.  For ~ 3000 rows this takes about 9-10 seconds, hence the need for something to keep a user amused.

I looked at using blockUI and this is great firstly, but the issue I had was how to unblock the UI after a file confirmation had been received.  I read a good article:

http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

So I ended up using jquery cookie and blockUI.  I also had an animated gif, which for some reason doesn't show under Firefox, but does under IE8 (!!!!).  Different issue entirely.

Now on the surface, the code in that article works.  I did up a test app and all was good, but when I applied this to the application I'm writing, it would fail to delete the cookie.  It turns out, that it doesn't like when I have the full url in the bar:

http://localhost:4790/Home.aspx/Index
^^ Global.asax.cs was changed due to the fact this application will be deployed on IIS6.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
            //"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index", id = "" } // trying for IIS6
            //new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        // New - trying for IIS6
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Root",
            "",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
    }
    /*

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }     // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
     * */
```

In the Controller, for the Index Action I have:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and in the Home Controller, again, I have a method which I'm "faking" sending back a file.  Which also sets the cookie "fileDownloadToken" to a value of "export".

```
    public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        byte[] test = new byte[1000];
        this.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", "export"));
        return File(test, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");
    }
```

The contents of the index view are:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<input id="save_button" type="button" value="Get" onclick='window.location.href=("@Url.Action("GetFile")")' />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save_button').click( function () {
        $.blockUI({
            message: $('#loading')
        });
        blockUIForDownload();
    });       

});

var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
function blockUIForDownload() {
    fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
        var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
        if (cookieValue == "export")
            finishDownload();
        }, 100);
}

function finishDownload() {
        window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
        $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null);
        $.unblockUI();
    }

</script>

<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
    <br />
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" /><br />
    <h2>Exporting, Please Wait...</h2>
</div>
```

Now, as I've stated above, it works when you browse directly to localhost: as designated by VS2010, but when you browse to localhost:/Home.aspx/Index it fails.

I've used developer tools on IE8 to debug and used alert's etc to alert the value of the cookie, and the cookie value remains even after calling $.cookie("XXXX", null).  I figure if it was some sort of pathing/domain issue, then you would not be able to get the value of the cookie at all, so it is the opposite in that, the UI unblocks straight after you press the button, but

Comment: FYI, I've fixed it, after mucking around on this all day and finally posting on here.  I ended up deleting the cookie with the command: $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null, { path: '/' });